# ProgressBar при переходе между страницами сайта.

Tags: php, javascript, css, html5

Есть страница **A** и страница **Б**. Как при **плохом** качестве подключения пользователю показывать ProgressBar. Подчеркиваю что это событие должно происходить именно при **ПЛОХОМ** качестве подключения к сети ! Спасибо!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А как вы собираетесь узнать, что у него плохое качество? Вообще вас спасет `Loader`, он плюс минус для такого и нужен. Чем быстрее страница будет грузиться, тем меньше по времени он будет, ну и плюс современно.

P.S. Как вариант, плохое качество можно задетектить с помощью `JS` смотреть за сколько секунд страница **A** грузится, если больше определенного времени - ставим куку (временную), и тогда при запросе страницы **Б**, смотрим наличие этой куки, если есть, то выкидываем лоадер.